# Volume mount when setting up Wordpress with docker

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, persistent-storage

[Quickstart: Compose and WordPress](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/) proposes the following `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    dbdata:
```

For persisting database data, a volume is created:

> - The docker volume `db_data` persists any updates made by Wordpress to the database.

but nothing is mentioned about the wordpress container...

**Questions:**

1. should I follow the same approach and create volumes for the `wordpress` container, in order to persist the data that are going to be added (by posts, uploads, themes)?
2. If yes, which paths / directories should I point to?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Maybe I've found something...

```
volumes:
   - wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

According to [this](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/wp-content-a-beginners-guide-to-wordpress-most-important-directory) article:

> ...`wp-content` contains all user-supplied content. Basically anything you can upload to your site ends up here. That doesn’t include anything you write, mind you. Those things are stored in the WordPress database.
>
> However, **as long as you have both the database and your `wp-content` folder, you can always get your site back**, even if everything else was lost.

This is also applied here: [Setting up WordPress with Docker](https://cntnr.io/setting-up-wordpress-with-docker-262571249d50)

---

To try it out:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
   image: mysql:5.7
   volumes:
     - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
   restart: always
   environment:
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
     MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
     MYSQL_USER: wordpress
     MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
   depends_on:
     - db
   image: wordpress:latest
   volumes:
     - wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
   ports:
     - "8000:80"
   restart: always
   environment:
     WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
     WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
     WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress

volumes:
  dbdata:
  wp-content:
```

Comment: you also need to add it to volumes block at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks @chovy, I added the relative `yaml`. So, for those who want to use [named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume-configuration-reference) they have to add it to the "top-level" `volumes` key too.

Comment: Now I wonder how to solve this using Docker swarm and some CDN, like aws s3 or digital ocean spaces.

Comment: @chovy Why is it necessary to add to volumes block?

Comment: i think it is better to add all the html folder to the volume, like : 
 volumes:
     - wp-content:/var/www/html

Answer (score 1):

replace volumes: with this one

```
volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
      - ./src:/var/www/html:cached
```