# Where are the WordPress files with Docker?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I'm getting started with running Docker on MacOS and I *just* was able to install a WordPress container and get that running locally.
But where the heck are the *actual* WordPress files?

Do I need to SSH into the container so I can view/edit them there? If so, how would one go about that?

Answer (score 9):

Wordpress files are kept inside the `container`, for example you can find `wp-content` at:

```
/var/www/html/wp-content
```

But, to get "inside" your running container you will have to do something like `docker container exec -it <your_container_name> bash`. More here: [How to get into a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-to-get-into-a-docker-container)

---

Containers are considered ephemeral, which means that a good practice is to work in a way that lets you easily stop/remove a container and spin up a new one without losing your stuff. To persist your data you have the option to use `volumes`.

---

You might also want to take a look at this, which worked for me: [Volume mount when setting up Wordpress with docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49202531/volume-mount-when-setting-up-wordpress-with-docker). If your case is to develop wordpress on docker containers, then... it's a different case.

Comment: FWIW you can use `docker ps` to get the container name

Answer (score 2):

If you have not set a binding when running the docker image for the first time you can still do the following.

```
docker volume ls
```

will list all of your volumes used by your local docker.
What you can do is the following :

```
docker volume inspect "VOLUME NAME"


e.g. docker volume inspect "181f5c9916a29e9f654317988f49237ea9067157bc94041176ab6ae5f9a57954"
```

you will find the Mountpoint of each docker volume. There could more than 1, every one of those will have a mount point.

Comment: So, do I need to set a bind to the image? Or SSH into the image?

Comment: You can set a binding before running it the first time by using -v /Users/myself/myfolder:/var/www/html if the wordpress container has the files at /var/www/html